# How to convert my json data to dataframe pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Hi i cannot seem to convert my json data to csv using python please help:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "application": "orders-prod",
        "host": "ldn001"

    },
    "OrdID": "123",
    "EventSeq": "328",
    "EventTS": "2019-04-17T01:01:14.569000Z"

}
{
    "metadata": {
        "application": "orders-prod",
        "host": "ldn001"

    },
    "OrdID": "234",
    "EventSeq": "328",
    "EventTS": "2019-04-17T01:01:14.569000Z"

}
{
    "metadata": {
        "application": "orders-prod",
        "host": "ldn001"

    },
    "OrdID": "554",
    "EventSeq": "328",
    "EventTS": "2019-04-17T01:01:14.569000Z"

}

df=pd.read_json('smallordersl.json',lines=True)
```

I tried the above but it doesn't work- i get the error ValueError: Expected object or value.

Answer (score 0):

Your json file is not per line as you specified.  See below notes in the documentation about reading json files.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

```
lines : boolean, default False
Read the file as a json object per line.
```

Below is an example of using lines=True in the parameter

```
pd.read_json('{"a":1,"b":2}\n{"a":3,"b":4}', lines=True)
```

Notice that the json file above has line1 and line2, separated by a new line (\n)

Comment: please give me the sample file that you are working on. Put it on a file sharing site and give me the link